# Neo4J query to get top N results

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I have a node called `Airports` containing data about airports, and a node called `Routes` that has has tons of flights from and to airports (`SourceID, DestinationID`).

The data on that node looks like the following:

| Airline | AirlineID | Source | SourceID | Destination | DestinationID | Codeshare | Stops | Equipment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2B | 410 | AER | 2965 | KZN | 2990 |  | 0 | CR2 |
| 2B | 410 | ASF | 2966 | KZN | 2990 |  | 0 | CR2 |
| 2B | 410 | ASF | 2966 | MRV | 2962 |  | 0 | CR2 |
| 2B | 410 | CEK | 2968 | KZN | 2990 |  | 0 | CR2 |

I have created relationship types (1) SOURCE & (2) DESTINATION that show direction to an other airport

1. SourceID -> DestinationID
2. DestinationID -> SourceID

I need to write a query to return the top 5 airports with the most flights in total (inbound / outbound).

When running the following code results are correct:

```
MATCH (f)-[:SOURCE]->(a:Airport) 
WITH a, COUNT(*) as Count 
RETURN a.name AS AirportName, Count AS TotalFlights 
ORDER BY Count DESC LIMIT 5;
```

If I try to run the following to get total  flights, result are not.

```
MATCH (f)-[:SOURCE]->(a:Airport)<-[:DESTINATION]-(f)
WITH a, COUNT(*) as Count 
RETURN a.name AS AirportName, Count AS TotalFlights 
ORDER BY Count DESC LIMIT 5;
```

Can anyone help me? I am new to NEO4J.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query returns no result because you assgined the same variable `f` twice for a single `route` node only. Therefore this query will count only Routes that have `SOURCE` and `DESTINATION` relationships to the same airport (which do not make much sense usually).

```
MATCH (f)-[:SOURCE]->(a:Airport)<-[:DESTINATION]-(f)
WITH a, COUNT(*) as Count 
RETURN a.name AS AirportName, Count AS TotalFlights 
ORDER BY Count DESC LIMIT 5;
```

As suggested by others, it should be enough to simply count the relationships (getting a node degree):

```
MATCH (a:Airport)
WITH a, SIZE((a)<-[:SOURCE|DESTINATION]-()) as numOfFlights 
RETURN a.name as airportName, numOfFlights
ORDER BY numOfFlights DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just count the relationships (i.e. count the degree of the airport node):

```
MATCH (a:Airport)
RETURN a.name as AirportName, size( (a)-[:SOURCE|DESTINATION]-() ) as TotalFlights 
ORDER BY TotalFlights DESC LIMIT 5;
```

There is also an apoc function for getting the node degree.